# Finding Appropriate Model

Tags: mixed-model, modeling

I am trying to figure out the model, or rather how to fit it, for the following joint probability:
$P(y_i,y_j)$ where $y_i, y_j$ are binary variables.

I have explicit expressions for the various probability values:
$P(y_i = 1, y_j = 1) = \exp\left(\beta^T x_i + \beta^T x_j + \gamma_{ij}\right)$
$P(y_i = 0, y_j = 1) = \left(1-\exp(\beta^T x_i)\right)\exp(\beta^T x_j)$
$P(y_i = 1, y_j = 1) = \exp\left(\beta^T x_i\right)\left(1-\exp\left(\beta^T x_j\right)\right)$
$P(y_i = 0, y_j = 0) = 1 - P(y_i = 1, y_j = 1) - P(y_i = 0, y_j = 1) - P(y_i = 1, y_j = 0)$

Assuming I have many pairs (i,j) and choose to approximate the likelihood with a pair-wise likelihood function of all of the pairs (i,j), how do I go about fitting this model?  My background is math, not stats or probability, which is why I don't have much of a feel for making an educated guess as to which model this looks like and how to approach this.  So I hope this is not an easy question and I am troubling you for something so small.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your exact data? And how is this related to mixed models? The general process of fitting such a model is somewhat simple. You write down a function that returns the negative sum of the log likelihoods and minimize this numerically. How this works in your case is dependent on the data.